# How do I display this join query in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT product_name, date_bought, total_price
FROM `order` o
JOIN `order_items` oi
ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
WHERE o.student_id = $id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC");
```

How do you display all rows in a table with php?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['product_name'];
    echo $row['date_bought'];
    echo $row['total_price'];
}
```

That's the general idea... You'll have to deal with formatting however you want... Also, take note that `mysql_query()` is *NOT* recommended. Please see [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) on what to use instead.